# How to make suggestions appear below the SearchBar

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, searchbar

I want to make the list of suggestions appear below the `SearchBar` like in [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchBar-class.html) example:
[image: Items appearing below]

I used the same code in the sample but the search box and the list goes fullscreen like this when the search bar is clicked:
[image]

Here's my code:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Add game'),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              SearchAnchor(
                builder: (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
                  return SearchBar(
                    controller: controller,
                    padding: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<EdgeInsets>(
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      controller.openView();
                    },
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        // Update the searchText and button enabled state.
                        searchText = value;
                        isButtonEnabled = searchText.isNotEmpty;
                      });
                      controller.openView();
                    },
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  );
                },
                suggestionsBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
                  return List<ListTile>.generate(5, (int index) {
                    final String item = 'item $index';
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(item),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          controller.closeView(item);
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  });
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: isButtonEnabled ? () => onAddToWatchlistClicked() : null,
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: lightColorScheme.primary
                ),
                child: const Text('Add to watchlist'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

I tried removing the other children, leaving only the `SearchAnchor` as the child but it didn't work. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. You just have to add `isFullScreen: false` to `SearchAnchor`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `viewConstraints` property and set `maxHeight` and `minHeight` like this:

```dart
SearchAnchor(
  viewConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 100,
    maxHeight: 400,
  ), ...
```